# Angular 2 App scrolls to top on its own

Tags: javascript, angular, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

Since the app is big I will try to simplify below:

TagComponent :

```
@Component({
  selector: "tag",
  template: `<div *ngFor="let a of arr">{{a}}</div>`
})
export class TagComponent{
  @Input() arr: string[];

  add(){
    this.arr.push("abc");
  }
}
```

AppComponent :

```
@Component({
  template: `<p><tag [arr]="data"></tag></p>`
})
export class AppComponent{
  data: string[];

  //some other code
}
```

So, when `add()` is called, only the first time the app scrolls to the top automatically and this only occurs in Outlook Desktop which is running a modified version of IE 11. Its a bit difficult to understand the problem and give a solution but any hints as to what might cause this will also count as an answer.